# SQLite3, не корректный вывод результатов запроса в массив

Tags: php, sql, sqlite, sqlite3, база-данных

Доброго времени суток. То ли я чего-то не пойму, то ли я разучился. Есть такой вот код:

```
$db = new SQLite3('../database/database.db');

$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users");

$users = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC);
var_dump($users);
```

По идеи он должен вывести все записи с таблицы, но выводит только одну.

[image: Вывод var_dump]

[image: Данные в таблице]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все делает правильно.

http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3result.fetcharray.php

`fetchArray` Забирает только один ряд.

если надо все то:

```
while($row = $result->fetchArray()) { 
    // ...
}
```

Если хочется все и сразу то перепешите на PDO(поддерживает SQLite)
http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.pdo-sqlite.php

http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.fetchall.php - вернет сразу все.

Comment: Спасибо. Не внимательно отнёсся к вопросу

Comment: роу это же интератор. можно в масив просто interatortoarray преобразовать. пишу  с телефона  мог ошибиться

Comment: @Naumov Вы о чём??